# Upgraded to 16.04 to 18.04 and can only log in, but nothing else. No network connection now. Getting error "apt-config: relocation error:..."

Tags: 18.04, upgrade

Upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.
Can log into system, but get no normal desktop tools, no keystrokes work, except ALT-CTRL-F1.
When logging in via that command line, receive error:

"apt-config: relocation error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-private.so.0.0: symbol _ZN9pkgSystem9LockInnerEv version APTKG_5.0 not defined in file libapt-pkg.so.5.0 with link time reference"

Receive this about 5 times when logging in at command line.

Also receive error that there is no network connection, although system is plugged into a known good network connection.

Cannot run anything requiribg an install since there is no network connection.

PLEASE HELP! SYSTEM IS DEAD IN THE WATER!